# How to access cell information after clicking on cell contentview's button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have the following code used to display some user information as well as a 'invite' button in a table cell. I am however not sure how I can access the cell's information e.g. user again when I click on the invite button (in 'inviteButtonPressed' method) since I am unable to pass any parameters to the button click method. Can anyone advise me how I can access the cell's information in the button click method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    GenericUser *user = [userSection objectAtIndex:row];

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        UIButton *inviteButton = [self setupButtonWithTitle:@"Invite" andFrame:CGRectMake(224, (44-24)/2, 56, 24)];
        [inviteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(inviteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        inviteButton.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:inviteButton];

     }

    UIButton *thisInviteButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    //This is where I will trigger the button press method
    [thisInviteButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UILabel *thisInvitedLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];

    cell.textLabel.text = user.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.email;
    if (user.isSelected) 
    {
        thisInviteButton.hidden = YES;

    }
    else
    {
        thisInviteButton.hidden = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}



-(void)inviteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //I want to access the cell information here. How can I do it? Basically I want to pass the user information belonging to the cell to this method

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass UIButton and add a property (let's call it selectedIndexPath) to hold an NSIndexPath. Instead of an UIButton you place your subclass on the cell and set the index path after the line `MyButton *thisInviteButton = (MyButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];`

than you can do

```
-(void)inviteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [((MyButton *)b) selectedIndexPath];
    GenericUser *user = [userSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


}
```

---

or another approach, without the need of custom buttons:

```
-(void)inviteButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell* cell =  (UITableViewCell*)[[b superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    GenericUser *user = [userSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

}
```

---

I am not sure, what approach I find less ugly.

Comment: I've generally prefer the first and have used it before, it's slightly less rigid as you can freely change the view hierarchy and it will still work.

Comment: Yeah, I think, you are right. and an advanced user can extend UIButton with a category and associated indexPath object, if subclassing is unwanted — for what reason ever.